# Which hash-function is used by Windows Installer?

Tags: windows-installer

An MSI-database contains a table [MsiFileHash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370107%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). According to the documentation *The MsiFileHash table is used to store a 128-bit hash of a source file provided by the Windows Installer package.*

Does someone know what hash algorithm is used/should be used to generate these hashes?
MD5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually just MD5, as the following program demonstrates:

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <msi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        if (argc != 2) {
                fprintf(stderr,"USAGE: %s FILENAME\n", argv[0]);
                return 1;
        }
        char *fileName = argv[1];
        MSIFILEHASHINFO hash;
        hash.dwFileHashInfoSize = sizeof(MSIFILEHASHINFO);
        int rc = MsiGetFileHashA(fileName,0,&hash);
        if (rc != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: Hashing '%s' failed with error %d\n",
                        fileName, rc);
                return 1;
        }
        size_t len = sizeof(hash.dwData);
        char *buf = (char*) &(hash.dwData[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                unsigned char ch = buf[i];
                printf("%02x", ch);
        }
        printf(" *%s\n",fileName);
        return 0;
}
```

Compile it (using MinGW-w64): `gcc -o msihash.exe msihash.c -lmsi`

Run it: `./msihash.exe ./msihash.exe`

Compare it to `md5sum` command output: `md5sum.exe ./msihash.exe`

You will observe the output is identical (except for one invisible difference, CRLF vs bare LF line terminators):

```
# ./msihash.exe ./msihash.exe  && md5sum.exe ./msihash.exe
9c794dc266d56d17fd1c50c908f28f17 *./msihash.exe
9c794dc266d56d17fd1c50c908f28f17 *./msihash.exe
```

Of course, you will get different hashes when you run the test, the point is they will both produce the same output. (The `*` in the `md5sum` output means this file was processed in binary not text mode, my test program above prints the same `*` just so its output is the same.)

While it is possible Microsoft may change this in the future (MD5 is now discouraged due to its cryptographic weakness), I assume if they ever did so, they would do it in a way which preserves backward compatibility–so the above code would still return MD5, but passing some flag in `dwOptions` (or a bigger `dwFileHashInfoSize`) would request a newer algorithm instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's a custom hash algorithm used only by Windows Installer.

Since Windows Installer uses it only for unversioned files, it's not reliable for file validation or integrity check. So you should use your own algorithm if you want to use file hashes in a custom way.

Comment: It's not a custom hash algorithm. It's just MD5. See my answer

Answer (score 2):

Use the MsiGetFileHash MSI API function to get the hash MSI itself uses.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple Powershell-snippet that demonstrates how to convert the 4 hash-parts in the MSI-database back into an MD5-hash:

```
cls
# this is the file-info in the MSI database (from Acrobat DC MSI)
# fileName as shown in file-table:
$file = "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\plug_ins\Annotations\Stamps\CompareMarkers.pdf"
# hashes as shown in MsiFileHash-table:
$msiFilehash = (932209603, -818443282, -2130858197, -300440504)

# get MD5 from real file:
$md5 = (Get-FileHash $file -Algorithm MD5).hash
write-host 'MD5' $md5

# get hash from the 4 hash-parts in the msi:
$hexbin = [System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapHexBinary]::new()
$parts  = foreach($part in $msiFilehash) {
    $hexbin.Value = [System.BitConverter]::GetBytes($part)
    $hexbin.ToString()
}
$msiHash = [string]::Concat($parts)
write-host 'MSI' $msiHash
```

Keep in mind, that the MsiFileHash-table is not a requirement in an MSI file. In most installs it does not exist.